# How can it get the user location in objective c with an iPhone and animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have an iPhone project in xcode, i've put a mapview and with the next code i show the user's location:`mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;`.
But i want that when the user opens the app the applications zooms with an animation automatically, i think that i need to put this code in the viewDidLoad method.
Finally i need to store the latitude into a variable, i tried to to that with the next code: `float latitud = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;` but the latituded that this returned was not the correct one of my location, i think that i need to do this with the CLLocationManager but i don't know how to do that.

Please, help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hiya - what kind of animation do you want? Do you mean the map zooms from the 'world view' down to 'street level' at the location of your user? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking this with simulator you won't get your location coordinate. Your xcode give apple head-quarters as the user location

mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

will work only in device.